# How to calculate the difference (in days) between two DateTime objects?

Tags: java, datetime, date, time, jodatime

I started playing with [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) and I failed to find a handy way to calculate the difference in days between 2 `DateTime` objects. The best I came up with is below:

```
    //given DateTime dt1 and dt2
    long distanceInMillis = dt2.getMillis()-dt1.getMillis();
    int distanceInDays = (int)(distanceInMillis / 24*60*60*1000L);
```

I would appreciate your suggestion of how this can be done better.

Comment: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/faq.html#datediff ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nooooooo!  So many Daylight Savings bugs from counting days using milliseconds :)

Joda provides

```
Days d = Days.daysBetween(dt1, dt2);
int days = d.getDays();
```